# Which idiom is correct "draw on" or "draw from"?

Tags: idioms, writing-style, idiom-meaning

Is there any difference in meaning between those two:

1. Gulf Racing draws **on** this history...
2. Gulf Racing draws **from** this history...

Are they both grammatically correct?

Comment: ***Draw on or draw upon*** to use something that you have gradually gained or saved. 
*As an actor, you often draw on your own life experiences.* http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/draw-on - ***draw from*** - something from somebody | draw something from something - 
*to take or obtain something from a particular source* - 
*to draw support/comfort/strength from your family* http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/draw-from

Comment: You probably need "draw on/upon" in your sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Both the Idioms draw on & draw from are correct and almost same meaning but are used in different contexts .

draw on :- to get any ideas or obtain any advice from someone . e.g. I may have to draw on your advice in order to complete this project. If there is some way you can draw on me to your advantage, let me know. By the end of the contest I had drawn upon all the energy I had.

Here the draw on tends to be more asking attitude , the user is not very sure and is in a state of uncertainty. He / She might be asking for some help .

draw from :- same as draw on , to get some inspiration from somebody . e.g. She drew her inspiration from her Parents. She draws majority of ideas from her Father.

Here the draw from sounds that the user has already decided what he / she is going to do and is talking about her experience . Lets say I draw my groceries from Walmart .....